# 3 OR conditions in single queryset filter

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to use 3 or statements in a single filter, but it isn't working.

```
cart = carts.filter(Q(status='completed') | Q(status='paid') | Q(status='started'))
```

Do you know what the correct syntax is?

Thanks!

Comment: It's seems to correct. Can you recheck?

Comment: ok, I'll try and get back to you

Comment: I forgot to import Q at the top of my views. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct:

`cart = carts.filter(Q(status='completed') | Q(status='paid') | Q(status='started'))`

You could simply use `in`:

`cart = carts.filter(status__in=['completed', 'paid', 'started'])`

---

When you say, it's not working I assume you're not getting any results. You should:
* check the actual `status` values you have in DB and the ones in you pre-filtered list `carts`:

```
set(Cart.objects.values_list('status', flat=True))    # full list of statuses
set(carts.values_list('status', flat=True))    # statuses for your pre-filter
```

---

Also consider using constants for your statuses (instead of strings).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to import Q at the top of my views :(